# Wordpress symbol in title

Tags: wordpress, title

I want to remove symbol  &raquo from title in wordpress. This symbol is add in every page before page title:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I5xf.png

Comment: Look into your code. It's css thing or it's added directly in the php files. We can't help more than this, since we don't know what's going on the other side...

Comment: I add trim in php and it`s ok. trim(wp_title(''));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_filter()` for this purpose.

A simple example would be like

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'lose_four_chars');

function lose_four_chars($title) {
if ( is_single()) {
    return substr($title, 4);
} else {
    return $title;
}
}
```

where `lose_four_chars` function can be replaced with your manual function..

Please have a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136145/deleting-first-four-characters-from-all-post-titles)